# I'm getting a error that "value of uitableviewcell has no member delegate" . is there anything that should be changed in Tviews.delegate = self

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates

I'm getting this error message in my table view controller class

> value of uitableviewcell has no member delegate

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfVFY.png) is an image of the error.

Is there anything that should be changed in my code?

```
import UIKit

class TViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var Tviews: UITableViewCell!
    
    let contacts:[[String]] = [
        ["Elon Musk",       "+1-201-3141-5926"],
        ["Bill Gates",      "+1-202-5358-9793"],
        ["Tim Cook",        "+1-203-2384-6264"],
        ["Richard Branson", "+1-204-3383-2795"],
        ["Jeff Bezos",      "+1-205-0288-4197"],
        ["Warren Buffet",   "+1-206-1693-9937"],
        ["The Zuck",        "+1-207-5105-8209"],
        ["Carlos Slim",     "+1-208-7494-4592"],
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         Tviews.delegate = self
         Tviews.datasource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViews", for: indexPath)

        print("\(#function) --- section = \(indexPath.section), row = \(indexPath.row)")

        cell.textLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row][0]

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `Tviews: UITableViewCell!` or ` Tviews: UITableView!`? `Tviews` is a `TableView` or a Cell?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Comment: First, thanks to @luca_999 for the edits - I was working through them also and was dealing with the image links. The error is that you are trying to make `Tviews` (which isn't the way a Swift coder would declare it - try `tViews` or `tViewCell` instead), a `UITableView` delegate. But you've declared it as a `UITableViewCell`. My suggestion? Call your table view `tViews` (or better `tableView`, call your cells `tViewCell`, and make `ViewController` be the delegate for `tableView` by declaring `taleView.delegate == self` in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should assign your delegate and data source to your table view instance, and not your table view cell.

In order to do that, create an outlet link with your table view in the TViewController file and then edit your code like this:

```
import UIKit

class TViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    let contacts:[[String]] = [
        ["Elon Musk",       "+1-201-3141-5926"],
        ["Bill Gates",      "+1-202-5358-9793"],
        ["Tim Cook",        "+1-203-2384-6264"],
        ["Richard Branson", "+1-204-3383-2795"],
        ["Jeff Bezos",      "+1-205-0288-4197"],
        ["Warren Buffet",   "+1-206-1693-9937"],
        ["The Zuck",        "+1-207-5105-8209"],
        ["Carlos Slim",     "+1-208-7494-4592"],
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.datasource = self
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contacts.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "<your-table-view-cell-id>", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = contacts[indexPath.row][0]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post an image or a message of the error you are getting?

Comment: `let cell = UITableViewCell()` no. Please dont do that. `dequeue` the cell.

Comment: @Larme mine is a generic example since the question doesn't contain details about the `UITableViewCell` instance.

Comment: But you are giving bad example. Prefers using `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViews", for: indexPath)` as the author has already, or `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "...", for: indexPath)` to show the good example. Because I know how often answers are just copied/paste...

Comment: @Larme Just edited my answer as you suggested. Thank you for your tips.